# python tarfile created an extra @PaxHeader file and cause error Cannot utime: Operation not permitted

Tags: python, linux, aws-lambda, tar, tarfile

I have a lambda function that unpack a tgz file, replace the content and filename, and then re-pack it into a new tgz file. If I download the new file from s3 and unpack it locally using 7z on Windows or `tar xvzf <new_file_name>.tgz` on Ubuntu, it all works fine. However if I sftp the new tgz file to a customer, they got utime error. They sent me the log like this

```
cd /usr/.../; tar xvzf </usr/.../new_file_name>.tgz;
./
./A/
./A/a.jpg
./A/b.jpg
./A/c.jpg
./something.xml
tar: .:Cannot utime: Operation not permitted.
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous error
```

I am wondering if the extra @PaxHeader file is causing the utime error because I can see from the log file that the contents are unpacked already.

Here is my lambda function code.

```
import os
import sys
import tarfile
import shutil
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
accepted_date = os.environ["Acceptable_Date"]
work_dir = '/tmp'  # os.getcwd() returns "/var/task"
new_dir = '/tmp/new'
current_date = ''

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        tmpkey = key.replace('/', '')
        if accepted_date in tmpkey:
            print('Already has the correct date. No processing')
        else:
            download_path = '{}/{}'.format(work_dir, tmpkey)

            current_date = get_current_date(tmpkey)
            newkey = tmpkey.replace(current_date, accepted_date)

            upload_path = '{}/{}'.format(work_dir,newkey.replace('tgz','tar.gz'))
            print(work_dir)
            s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
            process(upload_path)
            s3_client.upload_file(upload_path,bucket, newkey)

            cleanup(download_path)
            print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
            for entry in os.scandir(work_dir):
                print(entry.name)
            print('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb') 

    
def process(upload_path):
    for entry in os.scandir(work_dir):
        if entry.path.endswith(".tgz") and entry.is_file:
            print(entry.path)
            current_date = get_current_date(entry.name)
            decompress(entry.path)
            new_name = replace_content(current_date)
            compress2(upload_path)      

def get_current_date(file_name):
    return file_name.split('_')[1]

def decompress(file_name):
    tar = tarfile.open(file_name, "r:gz")
    tar.extractall(new_dir)
    tar.close()

def compress2(output_filename):
    # if using tgz as file extension, you cannot decompress it using 7z on Windows.
    # Do not add entry by entry. Add the source fold instead.
    for entry in os.scandir(new_dir):
        print('Included: '+entry.path)
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(new_dir, arcname='.')

def cleanup(output_filename):
    for entry in os.scandir(work_dir):
        if entry.is_file:
            remove(entry.path, False)
        else:
            remove(entry.path, True)
            
def replace_content(current_date): 
    for entry in os.scandir(new_dir):
        if entry.path.endswith(".XML") and entry.is_file():
            print(entry.path)
            new_path = entry.path.replace(current_date, accepted_date)
            with open(entry.path, "rt") as old:
                with open(new_path, "wt") as new:
                    for line in old:
                        new.write(line.replace(current_date, accepted_date))
            remove(entry.path, False)
            return new_path.replace('XML', 'tgz')

def remove(path, is_dir):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        if is_dir:
            shutil.rmtree(path)
        else:
            os.remove(path)
        print('Removed: '+path)
    else:
        print("The file does not exist: "+path)
```

Any idea what I have done wrong?

PS
The file permission for all content files and the tgz file are `-rwxrwxrwx` and the file owner is me if I download and unpack locally.

Comment: The utime error isn't a problem with your tar file -- it's a problem with the folks unpacking it not having enough privileges to modify the created files' access and modification times.

Comment: Consider suggesting that the customer use `-m` in addition to their existing tar flags. That is: `tar xmvzf new_file_name.tgz`

Comment: But if I send a new tgz file without @PaxHeader file (it's generated via 7z commandline), the customer will have no problem at all. Why is that? Just curious. `7z a -ttar -so new.tar .\ | 7z a -si new.tgz`

Comment: Presumably that header is what's providing the time information that `tar` on the customer side doesn't have enough permissions to apply to their filesystem. That's a guess, though, I'd want to look at an `strace` of the error taking place to say for sure.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're instructing the customer to use `tar` instead of `pax` if they're unpacking something formatted as a pax archive? (granted, _old_ systems are more likely to have some version of `tar` or another, but `pax` has been POSIX-specified for a while now).

Comment: We have been using tar. I am not aware that python format it as pax. I am newbie for python tarfile. So how can I make python to format it as tar? BTW, my customer won't change their system. Any tiny change is a big deal for them.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that `tarfile` creates pax archives, but you were talking about using 7zip to create them. (`pax` being POSIX-specified, it's supposed to come out-of-the-box with standard-compliant UNIX systems; it _also_ supports regular `ustar` and other tar variants).

Comment: ...anyhow, is the above to say that you can't ask the customer to just tell their copy of `tar` not to apply timestamps on unpack?

Comment: Alternately, you can pass `TarInfo` objects to `.add()` to have control over what timestamp information and other metadata is present. I'd want to look at the spec (to the extent that there is one -- the tar format having multiple competing specifications is part of why `pax` exists), but if zero'ing out the tar field means the client doesn't try to set a value, there you are.

Comment: ...do the timestamps in `tar -tvvzf yourfile.tar.gz`'s output differ between the two creation mechanisms? This is a bit of a WAG, but I could imagine your customer system refusing to allow timestamps to be set in the future, f/e, and differences between whether tools encode local time and UTC impacting that.

Comment: @Charles, Thank you for the comments. That helped alot, from which I found this `tar.format = tarfile.GNU_FORMAT`. That removed the @PaxHeader file. So I would assume the new.tgz is with tar format.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
tar = tarfile.open('sample.tar.gz', 'w:gz', format=tarfile.GNU_FORMAT)
```